# Unable to add product attribute programmatically

Tags: magento2, product, php

I cannot add the attribute `packaging_unit` to the products on my website.

The attribute does neither appear in the database table `eav_attribute` nor on the website on the product page nor in the backend. I'm running Magento 2.1.7

I have already read several tutorials, changed my code multiple times, but it just doesn't work.

My `module.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Test_ProductAttributes" setup_version="0.0.2">
  </module>
</config>
```

`registration.php`:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Test_ProductAttributes',
    __DIR__
);
```

`InstallData.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Test\ProductAttributes\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
* @codeCoverageIgnore
*/
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
    * Eav setup factory
    * @var EavSetupFactory
    */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
    * Init
    * @param CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
    */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
    * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
    * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
    */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'packaging_unit',
            [
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable,grouped',
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Packaging unit',
                'input' => 'text',
                'source' => 'Test\ProductAttributes\Model\Attribute\Source\PackagingUnit',
                'frontend' => 'Test\ProductAttributes\Model\Attribute\Frontend\PackagingUnit',
                'backend' => 'Test\ProductAttributes\Model\Attribute\Backend\PackagingUnit',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 50,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => true
            ]
        );

    }
}
```

`Model/Attribute/Source/PackagingUnit.php`:

```
class PackagingUnit extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    /**
    * Get all options
    * @return array
    */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

`Model/Attribute/Backend/PackagingUnit.php`:

```
class PackagingUnit extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend
{
    /**
    * Validate
    * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $object
    * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
    * @return bool
    */
    public function validate($object)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

`Model/Attribute/Frontend/PackagingUnit.php`:

```
class PackagingUnit extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\AbstractFrontend
{
    public function getValue(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $object)
    {
        $value = $object->getData($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode());
        return "<b>$value</b>";
    }
}
```

In the Magento root folder I run the following commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Both succeed without an error, but as I said it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the script I can see that you are trying to set custom option in your attribute by usbing `source model`. So I think you are trying to create attribute type for `dropdown` or `multiselect`. If yes then you should pass this attribute input type as `select` or `multiselect`.

So you can change input `type`

```
'input' => 'text',
```

Comment: When I change input type to select it still doesn't work. I added a write to file operation at the start of the install method. The file never gets written. I assume the method is never called. I also deleted the module's entry in the prefix_setup_module table since this might prevent the module from being installed. But is also doesn't work. What else could prevent the module from being installed?